# Using Azure functions (python), create an image from matplotlib and save it in azure blob storage

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I am looking to create an image file using matplotlib on a schedule, and save that image file to Azure storage blob.

```
import datetime
import logging
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import azure.functions as func
from io import BytesIO

import numpy as np


def main(mytimer: func.TimerRequest, mysecondblob: func.Out[bytes]):
    utc_timestamp = datetime.datetime.utcnow().replace(
        tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).isoformat()

    if mytimer.past_due:
        logging.info('The timer is past due!')

    logging.info('Python timer trigger function ran at %s', utc_timestamp)

    t = np.arange(0.01, 10.0, 0.01)
    data1 = np.sin(2 * np.pi * t)

    # plot it
    fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()
    ax1.set_xlabel('time (s)')
    ax1.set_ylabel('exp')
    ax1.plot(t, data1)

    image_stream = BytesIO()
    plt.savefig(image_stream)
    # reset stream's position to 0
    image_stream.seek(0)
    with BytesIO() as input_blob:
        mysecondblob.set(image_stream)
    # upload in blob storage
```

I keep getting the same type error **"Exception: TypeError: unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python type "BytesIO"**

TIA

---

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mytimer",
      "type": "timerTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "schedule": "* * * * * *"
    },
    {
      "name": "mysecondblob",
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      
      "path": "poweroutagepng/master.png",
      "connection": "checkingoutages"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Can you post your `function.json` file.

Comment: Sorry, that was sloppy. Just added!

Comment: Is this your whole code? Looks like there's something after `# upload in blob storage`

Comment: Yeah, should just use the .set() method on the output binding "mysecondblob" to put the .png on the azure storage blob. Do I have the func.Out[bytes] setting incorrect?

Comment: Can you add `"dataType": "binary",` to your `function.json`, see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-python) for example

Comment: I got this in return

** unable to encode outgoing TypedData: unsupported type "<class 'azure_functions_worker.bindings.generic.GenericBinding'>" for Python type "int" **

Should be easy but it's proving elusive

Comment: @Erfan I moved mysecondblob: func.Out[func.InputStream] and it worked. No idea why, and I am fairly sure whatever is now sitting in my blob container isn't useful, but there is something there.